# Search for all Domains in a Forest using ADSI in C++

Tags: c++, adsi

So I need to find all domains in the forest that a host is currently in.

According to everything I've read asking for "**namingContexts**" after opening the open **GC://RootDSE** Should give me this, but, I am only seeing naming contexts for the forest root. I've checked all the HW, all the DC are up and running, GC are good. I know the data is there since Get-ADForest shows the domains I'm looking for. What am I missing???

Here is the code :

```
HRESULT hr;
IADs* pGCContainer = NULL;
VARIANT varContainerRetVal;
std::vector<std::string> vecUPNSuffixes;
BSTR path = NULL;

// Initialize COM.

hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if(FAILED(hr)){
    LogInfo("CoInitialize failed hr = %08x",hr);
}

VariantInit(&varContainerRetVal);

// look for all other Domains in the forest
hr = getGCRootDSEContainerObject(&pGCContainer); // this does an ADsGetObject("GC://RootDSE",IID_IADS,(void**)pGCContainer);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pGCContainer)
{
    // get NamingContext
    hr = pGCContainer->Get(_bstr_t(LDAP_OBJ_NAMEING_CTX.c_str()),&varContainerRetVal);
    vecForestDomains = getVariantArrayContentsAsVector(varContainerRetVal); // as the name implies this moves a Variant Array into an std::vector<std::string>
    VariantInit(&varContainerRetVal);
};
```

This works to an extent, as I get 5 entries back, but only from the root domain, no other domains are listed. And the really weird part is I saw this actually work a day ago.

This is what I get now:

```
+       [0] "DC=boston,DC=com"  
+       [1] "CN=Configuration,DC=boston,DC=com" 
+       [2] "CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=boston,DC=com"   
+       [3] "DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=boston,DC=com"    
+       [4] "DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=boston,DC=com"
```

This is what I was seeing yesterday, No Code changes in between

```
+       [0] "DC=boston,DC=com"  
+       [1] "DC=southend,DC=boston,DC=com
+       [2] "CN=Configuration,DC=boston,DC=com" 
+       [3] "CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=boston,DC=com"   
+       [4] "DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=southend,DC=boston,DC=com"    
+       [5] "DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=boston,DC=com"
```

Comment: [`Active Directory Explorer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/adexplorer.aspx) always shows the first result for the domain I am a part of.